# DataSource's getConnection() ignores port

Tags: java, mysql, ssh, port

I try to create connection to the remote server via ssh tunnel. In my tries I used both jsch and putty.

```
int sshPort = 22;

Connection conn = null;
Session session = null;

try {
     //Set StrictHostKeyChecking property to no to avoid UnknownHostKey issue
     java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
     config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

     JSch jsch = new JSch();
     session = jsch.getSession("sshUser", "sshHost", sshPort);
     session.setPassword(sshPassword);
     session.setConfig(config);
     session.connect();

     session.setPortForwardingL(8806, "127.0.0.1", 3306);

     BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
     basicDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     //I can type here any value of port, does not matter connection will be created on port 3306
     basicDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8806/db");
     basicDataSource.setUsername("user");
     basicDataSource.setPassword("password");
 }
```

From this code I expect that some `sshHost:22` will be available in `localhost:8806`.

But I got instead of this `connection = dataSource.getConnection();` that always connected to database on `localhost:3306`.

[image]

As I said earlier, I also try to connect via Putty - result the same, connection by code ignores port.

P.S. Putty's tunnel only works when I connect to 'localhost:8806' at IDEA's database tools.

P.P.S. Thanks for [@Cool](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3719412/cool) advice now I'm able to make a tunnel from the code. But dataSource continues to ignore the port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should forward "8806" to "3306" not to the "22" port.
So I can't test it now but you should use following line

```
session.setPortForwardingL(8806, "sshHost", 3306);
```

Btw you can use following for that without need to putty etc.

```
ssh sshUser@sshHost -L 8806:localhost:3306
```

Comment: oh, I understand my mistake in the code, but can't to try it up right now.
What can be wrong with putty's tunnel?

Comment: it should be L8806 sshHost:3306 not localhost

Comment: unfortunately, all variants differs from my doesn't work even in idea's database tools (in case of putty tunnel).
In code all manipulations with ports don't help: dataSource open connection on :3306